# UEFI Intel RST RAID issue, can it be solved with MDADM?

Tags: intel, raid, mdadm

I had two disks running on RAID0 on a Gigabyte GA-X38-DQ6. They contained a Windows installation, although not used at all as I was running linux from another SSD disk.

They were running on the Intel SATA slots (Intel RST?). The RAID volume was marked as bootable on the configuration after UEFI POST. But then I deleted the Windows partitions on the RAID volume from `parted`, created new 'msdos' table with a single partition, encrypted with LUKS. Then rebooted the machine.

What happened next was that I couldn't get past UEFI POST and stuck at storage device enumeration, code 23.

I then had to clear CMOS and make sure RAID was disabled on the Intel SATA slots to get past POST and boot linux from the other SSD again. But I cannot enable RAID on that controller now to remove the RAID volume and mark it as not bootable (not sure what this impacts).

Does `mdadm` have the functionality to delete metadata on these two disks so that UEFI also would get updated so there's no RAID volume anymore?

```
sudo mdadm -E /dev/sda /dev/sdc

/dev/sda:
          Magic : Intel Raid ISM Cfg Sig.
        Version : 1.0.00
    Orig Family : 5373413e
         Family : 5373413e
     Generation : 00000380
  Creation Time : Unknown
     Attributes : All supported
           UUID : 1050b44e:85219cfd:076c3919:92d0fc44
       Checksum : 89441d1c correct
    MPB Sectors : 1
          Disks : 2
   RAID Devices : 1

  Disk00 Serial : PO949601DJ080BGN
          State : active
             Id : 00000000
    Usable Size : 156296192 (74.53 GiB 80.02 GB)

[intel]:
       Subarray : 0
           UUID : 1abe4081:e1409052:bcf4593b:1e59904b
     RAID Level : 0
        Members : 2
          Slots : [UU]
    Failed disk : none
      This Slot : 0
    Sector Size : 512
     Array Size : 312592384 (149.06 GiB 160.05 GB)
   Per Dev Size : 156296456 (74.53 GiB 80.02 GB)
  Sector Offset : 0
    Num Stripes : 610532
     Chunk Size : 128 KiB
       Reserved : 0
  Migrate State : idle
      Map State : normal
    Dirty State : clean
     RWH Policy : off
      Volume ID : 0

  Disk01 Serial : PO949602KP080BGN
          State : active
             Id : 00010000
    Usable Size : 156296192 (74.53 GiB 80.02 GB)
mdadm: /dev/sdc is not attached to Intel(R) RAID controller.
mdadm: /dev/sdc is not attached to Intel(R) RAID controller.
/dev/sdc:
          Magic : Intel Raid ISM Cfg Sig.
        Version : 1.0.00
    Orig Family : 5373413e
         Family : 5373413e
     Generation : 00000380
  Creation Time : Unknown
     Attributes : All supported
           UUID : 1050b44e:85219cfd:076c3919:92d0fc44
       Checksum : 89441d1c correct
    MPB Sectors : 1
          Disks : 2
   RAID Devices : 1

  Disk01 Serial : PO949602KP080BGN
          State : active
             Id : 00010000
    Usable Size : 156296192 (74.53 GiB 80.02 GB)

[intel]:
       Subarray : 0
           UUID : 1abe4081:e1409052:bcf4593b:1e59904b
     RAID Level : 0
        Members : 2
          Slots : [UU]
    Failed disk : none
      This Slot : 1
    Sector Size : 512
     Array Size : 312592384 (149.06 GiB 160.05 GB)
   Per Dev Size : 156296456 (74.53 GiB 80.02 GB)
  Sector Offset : 0
    Num Stripes : 610532
     Chunk Size : 128 KiB
       Reserved : 0
  Migrate State : idle
      Map State : normal
    Dirty State : clean
     RWH Policy : off
      Volume ID : 0

  Disk00 Serial : PO949601DJ080BGN
          State : active
             Id : 00000000
    Usable Size : 156296192 (74.53 GiB 80.02 GB)
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by first deleting RAID metadata with `mdadm` then writing zeros on the entire disks.

Then I could enable RAID on UEFI again and create a new fakeRAID, but figured software RAID with `mdadm` was probably better anyway.